# Add editor toolbar to Metabox

Tags: php, metabox, editor

I have multiples Metaboxes like this one :

```
function initialisation_metaboxes_home(){

    add_meta_box('home_extract_meta', 'Affichage home', 'ma_meta_function_home', 'produit_fr', 'normal', 'high');
    add_meta_box('home_extract_meta', 'Affichage home', 'ma_meta_function_home', 'produit_en', 'normal', 'high');
}

function ma_meta_function_home($post){

    $val = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_home_extract',true);
    echo '<label for="champ_home">7 lignes max : </label>';
    echo '<textarea id="champ_home" type="textarea" name="champ_home" style="width: 1000px" rows="10">'.$val.'</textarea>';
}

function save_metaboxes_home($post_ID){

    if(isset($_POST['champ_home'])){

        update_post_meta($post_ID,'_home_extract', esc_html($_POST['champ_home']));
    }
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes','initialisation_metaboxes_home');
add_action('save_post','save_metaboxes_home');
```

I need to add a custom toolbar (cf. image below) to this Metaboxes, but I can't found anything ...

[image: toolbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to add a custom toolbar (cf. image below) to this Metaboxes

Do you want to add a custom TinyMCE toolbar to the TinyMCE/visual editor, or do you want to turn a `textarea` into a TinyMCE editor?

If it is the latter one, here's a sample code for turning the *champ_home* `textarea` into a TinyMCE editor:

```
wp_editor( $val, 'champ_home', array(
    'textarea_name' => 'champ_home',
    'textarea_rows' => '10',
    // TRUE to output the minimal editor config, such as the Comment editor.
    'teeny'         => true,
) );
```

See:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/

Comment: It's working ! But a little problem, all of the fields are empty, like if the function don't get the old textarea value ...

Comment: For example in the `ma_meta_function_home()`, you have this: `$val = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_home_extract',true);`. So you'd write `wp_editor($val)`. If you had `$var_name = get_post_meta($post->ID,'{META_KEY}',true);`, then you'd write `wp_editor($var_name)`. And so on.. Hopefully you understand what I mean?

Comment: I understant, I have this (wich doesn't work) : 
    `$val = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_av_extract',true);

    echo '<label for="champ_home">12 lignes maximum : </label><br /><br />';
    wp_editor( $val, 'champ_home', array(
        'media_buttons' => true,
        'textarea_name' => 'champ_home',
        'textarea_rows' => 10
    ) );`

Comment: Try to change `update_post_meta($post_ID,'_home_extract', esc_html($_POST['champ_home']));` to `update_post_meta($post_ID,'_home_extract', $_POST['champ_home']);` in `save_metaboxes_home()`.

Comment: Not working either ...

Comment: Did you get the same problem when you don't use `wp_editor()`?

Comment: You should also change the `textarea_name` as in `'textarea_name' => 'champ_home'`. I mean, if the value is different for your other meta boxes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73831/discussion-between-ankomm-and-sally).